# How to make changes to a widget in another class in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm new to OOP and kivy, I created an exam time table, for each timetable there are 2 buttons **Edit** and **remove**.
I want whenever I click the **remove** button, a `remove_entry()` function from **Exam** class to be called and that function should remove that particular entry.
For **Edit** button, when clicked, a dialogbox will open with some textfields, I want by the time user cliked on **save** button, `make_changes()` function from **Exam** to be called and that function should make changes to some timetables.

**This is the python file**

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivymd.uix.picker import MDTimePicker
from kivy.metrics import dp
import datetime
Window.keyboard_anim_args = {'d': .2, 't': 'in_out_expo'}
Window.softinput_mode = "below_target"


class Menu(Screen):
    pass
    
#exam timetable screen
class Exam(Screen):
    exam_btn = ObjectProperty()
    dept_exam = ObjectProperty()
    
    def on_enter(self):
        for item in self.Entries():
            self.dept_exam.add_widget(item, 1)
    
    #automatically insert the saved entries
    def Entries(self):
        global num
        
        ##The saved entries
        #f = [line.strip() for line in open('courses.txt') if line.strip() != '']
        f = ['CSC 221@27/4/2021@03:00 - 06:00@Gado Nasko',
              'CSC 212@2/5/2021@02:00 - 04:00@Gado Nasko']
        L = [Factory.OneEntry() for i in range(len(f))]
        
        #set  data to each of the entry
        num = 0
        for entry in L:
            items = f[num].split('@')
            entry.ids.exam_index.text = str(num+1)
            entry.ids.code.text = items[0]
            entry.ids.date.text += self.manp_date(items[1])
            entry.ids.time.text += items[2]
            entry.ids.venue.text += items[3]
            num += 1
            
        return L
    
    #add an entry by releasing the add button
    def adds(self):
        global num
        
        num += 1
        new = Factory.OneEntry()
        new.ids.exam_index.text = str(num)
        self.dept_exam.add_widget(new,1)
        

    #change date format
    def manp_date(self, dt):
        dy,mt,yr = dt.split('/')
        x = datetime.datetime(int(yr), int(mt), int(dy))
        return x.strftime('%d %b, %Y')
    
    #this should be called from TimeTabelApp
    def make_changes(self, change):
        pass
    
    #this should remove entry
    def remove_entry(self):
        pass
        
        
        
#The dialog box for editing an entry class
class Content(BoxLayout):
    #setting date function
    def show_date(self):
        self.ids.date_ent.hint_text = ''
        self.ids.date_ent.helper_text_mode = 'persistent'
        self.ids.date_ent.helper_text = 'dd/mm/yyyy'
    
        
    #setting time function
    def get_time(self, instance, time):
        self.ids.from_time.text = time
        self.ids.from_time.hint_text = ''
        self.ids.from_time.helper_text_mode = 'persistent'
        self.ids.from_time.helper_text = 'From'
    
    def show_time_picker(self):
        time_dialog = MDTimePicker()
        time_dialog.bind(time=self.get_time)
        time_dialog.open()

class MainMenu(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file('newfile.kv')



class TimeTableApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return kv
    
    #The dialog box for editing an entry function
    dialog = None
    def show_exam_dialog(self, counter):

        if not self.dialog:
            self.dialog = MDDialog(title="Set: Time, Venue, ...",
                                type="custom", content_cls=Content(),
                                    buttons=[ MDFlatButton(text="CANCEL", on_release=self.close_dialog,
                                                            text_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color),
                                                  MDFlatButton(text="SAVE", on_release=self.save_dialog,
                                                            text_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color)])
        self.dialog.open()
        self.dialog.set_normal_height()
     
     #closing editing dialog
    def close_dialog(self, *args):
        self.dialog.dismiss()
    
    #saving changes from dialog
    def save_dialog(self, inst):
        exam_code = self.dialog.content_cls.ids.exam_code
        from_time = self.dialog.content_cls.ids.from_time
        date_ent = self.dialog.content_cls.ids.date_ent
        exam_venue = self.dialog.content_cls.ids.exam_venue
        
        change = exam_code.text.upper()+'@'+date_ent.text+'@'+exam_venue.text.title()
        #self.Exam().make_change(change)
        self.dialog.dismiss()
            
      
if __name__ == '__main__':
    TimeTableApp().run()
```

**This is the kv file**

```
MainMenu:
    Menu:
    Exam:

<Menu>:
    name: 'menu'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        
        Button:
            text: 'Exam Timetable'
            on_release: app.root.current = 'exam'
    


<Exam>:
    name: 'exam'
    dept_exam: dept_exam

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: [0,20,0,0]
        
        ScrollView:
            effect_cls: 'ScrollEffect'
            GridLayout:
                id: dept_exam
                size_hint:(1, None)
                width: self.minimum_width
                height: self.minimum_height
                cols: 1
                spacing: 30
                padding: [10]
         
                
                #add entry button layout
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    size_hint: 1, None
                    height: 150
                    
                    Button:
                        id: btn
                        size_hint: None,1
                        width: 150
                        text: '+'
                        font_size: 80
                        background_color: 0,0,0,0
                        pos_hint: {'center_x':.5}
                        on_release: root.adds()
                        canvas.before:
                            Color:
                                rgba: (.7, .1, .4, 1) if self.state=='normal' else (0,.7,.7,1)
                            RoundedRectangle:
                                size: self.size
                                pos: self.pos
                                radius: [80]

#An entry class
<OneEntry@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 250
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0, 117/255, 1, 1)
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: [20]
    
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size_hint_y: .45
        Label:
            id: exam_index
            bold: True
            italic: True
            color: (114/255, 47/255, 55/255, 1)
            
        Label:
            id: code
            bold: True
            text_size: self.size
            halign: 'left'
            size_hint_x: 1.8
            font_size: 43
            
    #line
    Separator:
    
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        GridLayout:
            rows: 2
            size_hint_x: .8
            Label:
                id: date
                markup: True
                text: '[size=35][b]Date:[/b][/size] '
            Label:
                id: time
                markup: True
                text: '[size=35][b]Time:[/b][/size] '
                
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Label:
                id: venue
                markup: True
                text: '[size=35][b]venue:[/b][/size] '
                text_size: self.size
                halign: 'left'
                valign: 'middle'
            Label:
                text_size: self.size
                halign: 'left'
                valign: 'middle'
                markup: True
                text: '[size=35][b]Status:[/b][/size] '
                
    GridLayout:
        size_hint_y: .6
        padding: [20,10]
        cols: 2
        spacing: 10

        Button:
            text: 'Edit'
            background_color: (0, 117/255, 1, 1)
            on_release: app.show_exam_dialog(root.ids.exam_index.text)
        Button:
            text: 'Remove'
            background_color: (1, 0, 0, 1)
            on_release: root.remove_entry()


<Separator@Widget>
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 1
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            
            
<Content>
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: "12dp"
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 550

    MDTextField:
        id: exam_code
        hint_text: "Course Code"
        max_text_length: 7
        helper_text_mode: 'on_focus'
        helper_text: 'Not more than 7 character'
        required: True

    
    MDTextField:
        id: from_time
        hint_text: "Set Time"
        on_focus: if self.focus: root.show_time_picker
           
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: 5
        
        MDLabel:
            text: 'Set Date'
        
        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            MDTextField:
                id: date_ent
                on_focus: if self.focus: root.show_date() 
                hint_text: "dd/mm/yyyy"
                required: True
    
    MDTextField:
        id: exam_venue
        hint_text: "Venue"
        max_text_length: 20
        helper_text_mode: 'on_focus'
        helper_text: 'Not more than 20 character'
        required: True
```

Comment: I reccommend you create a 'Timetable' class specifically. It could be a widget or just an object but by creating it, you could limit the scope of the function 'remove_entry' so that you would 'remove the entry' more easily.

Comment: @Darnell Baird, how do you mean

Comment: @Abudl, my bad. Your 'Exam' class was what I was talking about. You already have it.

Answer (score 0):

### Question 1

In Kivy, you could bind events. Either in [kvlang](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#event-bindings) or in [Python](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/events.html#attaching-callbacks).

```
Exam:
...
    Button:
        text:"Remove Button"
        on_release: root.remove_entry()    #'root' is a keyword
```

### Question 2

To get a dialogbox, I recommend you use a [Popup](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.popup.html) widget.
To open the popup in code.

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory #at the start of kv script
...
MyPopup@Popup:
    title:"Whatever Title"
    Content:
    ...
...
Button:
    Button:
        text:"Edit"
        on_release:Factory.MyPopup()
```

Under the save button, put in:

```
on_release: app.save_dialog(self)     #'app' is a keyword
#I am not sure what 'inst' argument represents.
```